# Common standard for video formats used for matlab image analysis?

Tags: performance, matlab, video, format

I'm doing some simple video analysis in matlab for detecting motion (videos are about 1 hour each), and the biggest roadblock so far is the slow frame loading speed using videoreader.  I started with the H.264 codec, but the frame loading was painfully slow (47 seconds to load the first 50 frames) and I noticed an incremental frame read time similar to what is posted [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/257082).

I realise there is a trade off between disk space, and decompression time while choosing a format and there is no "perfect answer".  However, I was wondering if there are "common standards" typically used when it comes to selecting what format of video to use for image analysis in Matlab which give a fair balance between disk space used and decompression time.

Any ideas?

I'm using Matlab R2013a (Mac), and using VideoReader to load the videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I do video analysis using MatLab I first split the video in single frames (or I store 1 in 2 frames depending on the analysis of course) by using the scene video filter in VLC:

https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/vlc-export-frames/

Then I simply read the images using imread() in MatLab

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/imread.html

I never tried reading the frames with VideoReader because I like to have the seperate frames stored. However, I can imagine that VLC is more efficient at decoding video than MatLab is (due to decoding being their core business).

The performance I get using VLC to split the video in JPEG files for a 720x567 video is real-time (25fps dvsd).

I hope this works for.

Comment: Not the answer i was looking for, but u did point me in the right direction and provided a pretty good alternative.  I chose to encode in mjpeg format because of the exclusively intraframe compression.  Pretty much functionally the same as using jpegs, but makes file management a LOT easier.  Also, the encoding time for mjpeg is really fast (faster than real time) and by batch reading in 50 frames at a time, i can get a significant performance boost compared to reading one frame or image at a time.